# ajax .done not running properly, seems to skip code

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have the code bellow running in a `.each` function. However when all is set and done and i do `alert(inserted);` or alert of any other variable they come out `0` which is what i have them set as when i declare them. I am sure they are within scope. I have a feeling this has to do with the timing of the ajax because if i put an alert after each call, the counter system works. Any thought? Also I am sure that the proper if statements are called as I attached alerts (as i said above which when i do this the counter works) and they fire properly AND no error codes as brought up from the consol.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/php/filename.php",
    data: {
        one: $('#1').val(),
        two: $('#2').val(),
        three: $('#3').val(),
        four: $('#4').val(),
        five: $('#5').val(),
        six: $('#6').val(),
        seven: $('#classlist').val(),
        id: $('#7').html()
    }
}).done(function(msg) {
    if (msg == "inserted") {
        inserted++;
    }
    else if (msg == "updated") {
        updated++;
    }
    else if (msg == "duplicate") {
        duplicate++;
    }
    else if (msg == "0") {
        fail++;
    }
});
```

Comment: I was editing it for your liking but someone beat me to it, sorry for the pain I caused your eyes, It came out like that after copy paste from my editor.

Comment: alert the msg and see the response...

Comment: I do, and this makes everything work. This issue is when I run all the ajax calls with no alerts (pauses) then try to access anything it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ajax is asynchronous, your alert is happening before the ajax is complete. Store all of your ajax return values in an array, pass them all to .when, and then use it's done to alert the value of your variable.

```
var promiseArr = [], inserted = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 30000; i++) { // <--- unrealistic number of iterations
    promiseArr.push($.ajax({url:"foo.php?id=" + i}).done(function(){
        inserted++;
    }));
}
$.when.apply($,promiseArr).done(function(){
    alert(inserted);
});
```

Comment: I will try this now, but how would this cause my issue? is the next ajax call called before the return of the 1 ajax call? shouldnt that be prevented by .done? as all my responses should come back as some point or another?

Comment: no, all of your ajax requests are sent at once. They may even be finishing out of order. The code after the ajax request is executed before the ajax request is complete (before the .done gets called)

Comment: OHHH! i see what you mean, i cant believe i did not see/think about that! ok let me look everything over! Thanks!